# Local Variable memory in recursive calls in Java

Tags: java, variables, recursion, local

Local variables are stored in stack frame in recursive calls.

Based on my understanding  this means that whenever a recursive method is called, local variables will have different memory locations (ex. 1) result id will be different for every recursive call in the code below )

I tested code below, but I have the same memory location for the local variable result as 1) result id = 705927765

I don't understand why?

Why does it have the same memory location?

```
public class Test {
    static int sum_correct1( int[] A, int n ) {
        int result = 0;

        System.out.println("1) result id = " + System.identityHashCode( result ));

        if( n < 0) 
            result = 0;
        else {
            int smallResult = sum_correct1( A, n - 1 );
            System.out.println("\n2) A[" + n + "] = " + A[n] + " smallResult id = " + System.identityHashCode( smallResult ));
            result = smallResult + A[n];
            System.out.println("3) result id = " + System.identityHashCode( result ));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println( "sum correct 1 = " + sum_correct1(A, A.length - 1) ) ;
    }
}
```

```
1) result id = 705927765
1) result id = 705927765
1) result id = 705927765
1) result id = 705927765
1) result id = 705927765
1) result id = 705927765

2) A[0] = 1 smallResult id = 705927765
3) result id = 366712642

2) A[1] = 2 smallResult id = 366712642
3) result id = 1829164700

2) A[2] = 3 smallResult id = 1829164700
3) result id = 2018699554

2) A[3] = 4 smallResult id = 2018699554
3) result id = 1311053135

2) A[4] = 5 smallResult id = 1311053135
3) result id = 118352462
sum correct 1 = 15
```

Comment: `hashCode()` and `identityHashCode()` have nothing to do with location.

Comment: `System.identityHashCode` for an `int` has even less to do with location, as it's just going to box the `int` and then return the identity hash code of the `Integer`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: true for `hashCode()` but not that much for `identityHashCode()`. There is huge probability that two different objects will be given different `identityHashCode()`. Technically it depends on JVM but is/was usually based on either original memory address or internal per-thread counter. The opposite is completely true, so @user2761895 is right - when two objects have different `identityHashCode()` they are different objects at different locations.

Answer (score 0):

When passing a primitive type to `System.identityHashCode()` method, the variable is wrapped into appropriate object (`java.lang.Integer` in this case). JVM tries to cache `Integer` wrappers for small integers (-1024 - 1023 I think) and therefore it will always result into same object.

Try to modify your code to result into higher numbers and you'll get different identity hash codes.